# Subroutine declares new variable using passed in string as its name

Tags: perl

**What I'm looking for to do is to:** Pass a name (just a string) to a subroutine and let the subroutine declare a new variable with that passed in name.

**Explanatory Example 1 (Simplified):**

```
$name = "MyVariable";
declareNewVariable($name); #This line should work exactly as "my $MyVariable;"

sub declareNewVariable {
    my $newVariableName = shift;
    #…: Here should be a line to declare the new variable named by the passed string,
       #which I'm looking for.
}
```

---

**Explanatory Example 2 (More Detailed):**

```
$text = 'hello';
convert_to_uppercase_new($text,"CustomName");
    #Doesn't use declaration syntax each time I use the subroutine.
print $text; #Prints: hello
print $CustomName; #Prints: HELLO

sub convert_to_uppercase_new {
    #Should convert text to upper case then store the result in a new variable

    my ($content, $newVariableName) = @_;
        #The subroutine takes in the string to be converted to upper case
        #and another string to be used as the new variable name.

    …$newVariableName… = uc $content; 
        #dots (placeholder) represent blank space that should be filled with some
        #syntax that helps to declare the new variable with the name (string)
        #stored in $newVariableName.
}
```

The same thing could be achieved by simply making the subroutine return a value:

```
$text = 'hello';
my $CustomName = convert_to_uppercase($text);
    #Uses declaration syntax each time I use the subroutine.    
print $text; #Prints: hello
print $CustomName; #Prints: HELLO

sub convert_to_uppercase {
    #Simply returns the result

    my ($content) = @_;

    return uc $content; 
}
```

---

The reason I want to use this is not to re-type declaration syntax each time I use the subroutine `my $newVariable = convert_to_uppercase(param);`. Instead, I want to only use the subroutine call without new variable declaration syntax `convert_to_uppercase_new(param1,param2);` I see it simpler and nattier.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You can't do that. If you could, what would you use it for?

Comment: People ask [similar things](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+variable+variable+name+site:stackoverflow.com) on SO all the time, and the answer is always the same: don't do it.

Comment: By definition, a variable can't be declared at runtime. You can create one (by simply accessing it), but you can't declare one, which is the entire reason you shouldn't do it.

Comment: You can do `convert_to_uppercase_new($text, my $CustomName)`. That's only 1 character longer than `convert_to_uppercase_new($text, "CustomName")`.

Comment: @melpomene Great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Obligatory: [Why it's a bad idea to use a variable as a variable name](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)